# ES6 - Default parameter combined with Destructuring : What does this pattern mean?

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, ecmascript-6

I've seen these pattern in a CodeReview question:

```
toggleModal({title = null, description = null, cancelLabel = 'No', submitLabel = 'Yes'} = {}) {
    this.setState({
        modalVisible: !this.state.modalVisible,
        title: title,
        description: description,
        cancelLabel: cancelLabel,
        submitLabel: submitLabel
    });
},
```

The complete post: 
https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/141699/react-modal-visibility-and-content-toggling-based-on-action-clicked

I would say it's a combination of ES6 Default Parameter with Destructing.

Have tried to understand the purpose. But still no idea.

Why aren't Default Parameters used alone?

**Can anyone explain me what this pattern is about?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I would say it's a combination of ES6 Default Parameter with Destructuring.

In JavaScript we call them "arguments," not parameters, but yes, that's what that is. There are three parts to it. Let's build it up part by part:

1. Destructuring. In the function, we want to use `title`, `description`, etc. as locals, so we declare the destructuring argument:

   ```
   // Just the destructuring
   toggleModal({title, description, cancelLabel, submitLabel}) {
   ```
2. We want those individual properties to have default values, so we assign them defaults:

   ```
   // Add in defaults for the props
   toggleModal({title = null, description = null, cancelLabel = 'No', submitLabel = 'Yes'}) {
   // ---------------^^^^^^^-------------^^^^^^^-------------^^^^^^^-------------^^^^^^^^
   ```
3. We want to *also* make the entire object optional, so we assign a default to the object:

   ```
   // Add in a default for the object as a whole
   toggleModal({title = null, description = null, cancelLabel = 'No', submitLabel = 'Yes'} = {}) {
   // ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------^^^^^
   ```

So this:

```
toggleModal();
```

e.g., no argument, does the same thing this does:

```
toggleModal({});
```

...because the overall default (#3 above) kicks in, which does the same thing this does:

```
toggleModal({title: null, description: null, cancelLabel: 'No', submitLabel: 'Yes'});
```

...because the individual defaults (#2 above) kick in.

Because the argument is destructured, the function can use `title`, `description`, etc. within the body (#1 above).

Here's a simpler example:

```js
// REQUIRES ES2015+ SUPPORT IN YOUR BROWSER
function adams({answer = 42, question = "Life, the Universe, and Everything"} = {}) {
  console.log("Answer: " + answer);
  console.log("Question: " + question);
}

adams();
console.log("--");
adams({answer: 67});
console.log("--");
adams({question: "The mice are revolting!"});
console.log("--");
adams({
  question: "Would you like a piece of cake?",
  answer: "Yes, please!"
});
```

Output:

```
Answer: 42
Question: Life, the Universe, and Everything
--
Answer: 67
Question: Life, the Universe, and Everything
--
Answer: 42
Question: The mice are revolting!
--
Answer: Yes, please!
Question: Would you like a piece of cake?
```

Comment: I think I got: It's your to substitute the whole object (when no object has been assigned at all) with an object with default properties. As well as adding default properties to an 'incomplete object' (an object which lacks one or more parameter). Have I get it right?

Comment: @mizech: I'm not sure I understood that. The `= {}` part is what makes `toggleModal()` work (the case where we're not giving any argument), it provides a default for the argument. The `{title = null...` and such provide defaults for the properties of the object (and destructure it).

Comment: Tinkered a bit around with and it has become clear to me. :) Thanks a lot. You made my day. :))

Comment: @mizech: No worries, glad that helped. I updated the answer a bit to (try to) make it clearer.